# Show that $\frac {1}{3+x^2+y^2} + \frac {1}{3+y^2+z^2} +\frac{1} {3+x^2+z^2}\leq \frac {3}{5} . $

Tags: inequality, summation, symmetric-polynomials, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, muirhead-inequality

Let $x, y, z>0$ s.t. $x+y+z=3$.

Show that $$\frac {1}{3+x^2+y^2}  + \frac {1}{3+y^2+z^2} +\frac{1 } {3+x^2+z^2}\leq \frac {3}{5}\ . $$

My idea: $$3 + x^2 + y^2 \geq 1 + 2x+ 2y=7-2z $$
I notice that $f (t)=\frac {1}{7-2t} $  is a convex function but it's uselessness.

Also I have some troubles with the next inequality  $$\frac {a}{a^2+bc} +\frac {b}{b^2+ac}+\frac {c}{c^2+ab}\geq \frac {3}{2} \frac{a+b+c}{a^2+b^2+c^2} $$
My idea is to multiply and to apply Muirhead's inequality. But there are too much terms.

Comment: This has two problems in one post. You need to maintain one per post, as is the norm here. Else you will have people posting entire question papers and others not being able to figure if a certain question has ever been posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first inequality.

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{3+x^2+y^2}\leq\frac{3}{5}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{3+x^2+y^2}-\frac{1}{3}\right)\leq\frac{3}{5}-1$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2+3}\geq\frac{6}{5}.$$
Now, by C-S twice we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2+y^2}{x^2+y^2+3}\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+y^2+3)}=$$
$$=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(2x^2+2\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(x^2+z^2)}\right)}{2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+9}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(2x^2+2(x^2+yz)\right)}{2(x^2+y^2+z^2)+(x+y+z)^2}=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(4x^2+2xy)}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(3x^2+xy)}\geq\frac{6}{5}$$ because the last inequality it's $$\sum_{cyc}(x-y)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: @Micheal why don’t you put the second inequality answer in a different post answer - I see a newer post asking for this.

Answer (score 1):

The second inequality.

By C-S we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a}{a^2+bc}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2(b+c)^2}{(a^3+abc)(b+c)^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}a(b+c)\right)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3+abc)(b+c)^2}=\frac{4(ab+ac+bc)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3+abc)(b+c)^2}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that
$$8(ab+ac+bc)^2(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq3(a+b+c)\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3+abc)(b+c)^2$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}(5a^4b^2+5a^4c^2-6a^3b^3+4a^4bc-5a^3b^2c-5a^3c^2b+2a^2b^2c^2)\geq0,$$ which is obvious by Schur
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^4bc-a^3b^2c-a^3c^2b+a^2b^2c^2)\geq0$$ and Muirhead.